# How to create mass amounts of test data in elasticsearch / Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to test some logic I have written in Kibana (Vega scripts).  For this I require quite a bit of data to generate the graphs.  I am currently doing this manually wiht statements such as:

> post  /metrics-hardware-xxx/_doc {"@timestamp":"2023-03-11T15:00",
> "system_Status": 1 }  post  /metrics-hardware-xxx/_doc
> {"@timestamp":"2023-03-11T15:01", "system_Status": 1 }  post
> /metrics-hardware-xxx/_doc {"@timestamp":"2023-03-11T15:02",
> "system_Status": 0 }

BUt I would like to have some kind of for loop
where I can loop through timestamps 1 per minute over several days and assign a random system status either 0,1,2.

Is this possible in Elastic?

It is straightforward with a stored procedure in most sql DBs, but I am not sure where to start , and seems there is not much info on the web.

Comment: I don't think `elasticsearch` has a tool just for that. For quick and dirty I use `python` script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked ElasticSearch support directly and their answer confirms comment from @Paulo  .  It seems it is impossible to do that directly in Elastic, they recommend:

1. use one of the available client API (Python, c#, java...)
2. use Curl requests
3. use the PostMan application

I have decided to use the c# client which seems to be the most flexible.

Answer (score 1):

[Elastic Rally](https://github.com/elastic/rally) can help you to create dummy test data.

Comment: this looks good but it requires linux,  I am looking for a windows solution